# How can i reset text in contentEditable use by useRef?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a very simple app.

I want change empty string, if it has some char.

Check up a comment line.

```
const TagInput: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const domInputRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const onInput = useCallback((e: React.FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const value = domInputRef.current?.innerText ?? '';
    
    // if last char is space, I will change empty.
    if (value.charCodeAt(value.length - 1) === 160) {
      domInputRef.current?.innerText = "";  // <- here, error! 
      // TS said "Invalid left-hand side in assignment expressio"
    }
  }, []);

  return (
      <div
        contentEditable={true}
        onInput={onInput}
        ref={domInputRef} />
  );
};
```

Comment: You cannot do this `domInputRef.current?.innerText = ""` because of if the current is undefined you cannot set innerText you need to check with a null check before setting the value. Like `if(domInputRef.current) { domInputRef.current.innerText = "" }`.

Comment: Oh. I got it. Thanks! I forgot null check what it do.